# sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar analyze error after upgrade to SonarQube 6.0

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We just upgraded to SQ 6.0 and now some projects get the following error when analyzing with maven:

```
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) @ gitlab-hook-dispatcher ---
[INFO] User cache: C:\Users\frank.jakop\.sonar\cache
[INFO] Load global repositories
[INFO] Load global repositories (done) | time=94ms
[INFO] User cache: C:\Users\frank.jakop\.sonar\cache
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=5ms
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.0
[INFO] Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=162ms
[INFO] Execute project builders
[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=73ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.419 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-14T08:29:20+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 67M/495M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar (default-cli) on project gitlab-hook-dispatcher: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Last part of trace is

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.readPage(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:99)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:102)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:63)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    ... 72 more
```

This happens also when we use `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar` and seems to be project specific, some projects work and some don't.

Can anyone provide a hint what's wrong here?

Comment: delete the directory data/es in your SonarQube installation. It will recompute all the ES indexes

Comment: I had a similar issue on 5.6.1 (stacktrace seems very similar only the line numbers are slightly off). Clearing the data/es folder fixed it.

Comment: I had the same problem. Deleting the ES indexes worked for me...

Comment: I would like to add, this issue might not be version related as I'm running with `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Credit to @teryk-sonarsource-team, just making it an answer:

1. Delete the directory data/es in your SonarQube installation.
2. Restart SonarQube.

It will recompute all the ES indexes.

This resolved the problem for me in SonarQube 5.6.3.

Comment: I had the same issue and deleting 'data/es' was part of the solution. However, I had to restart my Sonarqube instance in order to take effect. Many thanks

Comment: @SylvesterAbreu Made restart explicit in answer.

Comment: Note that rebuilding ElasticSearch index is (as always) just a _workaround_. Underlying issue has been identified, it is tracked @ [SONAR-8887](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8887) and will be fixed in future versions.

Comment: I have installed Sonarqube on a docker container on Ubuntu. Where can i find my ES directory. Any clues ?

Comment: This solution worked for me when upgraded from Sonar 5.6LTS to 6.7LTS, thanks !