# Issues running `mvn sonar:sonar`

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm invoking sonar with:
    `mvn -X install sonar:sonar`

But I'm getting this result:

```
[INFO] 12:30:06.005 Load project repositories
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.061 GET 200 http://<ip>:9000/batch/project.protobuf?key=<key> | time=55ms
[INFO] 12:30:06.171 Load project repositories (done) | time=166ms
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.183 using CxxProjectBuilder
[INFO] 12:30:06.184 Execute project builders
[INFO] 12:30:06.249 Execute project builders (done) | time=65ms
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.315 Available languages:
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.315   * c++ => "c++"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.315   * Python => "py"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.315   * JSON => "json"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.316   * JavaScript => "js"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.316   * Puppet => "pp"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.316   * C# => "cs"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.316   * Java => "java"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.316   * Groovy => "grvy"
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.316   * XML => "xml"
[INFO] 12:30:06.324 Load quality profiles
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.378 GET 200 http://<ip>:9000/api/qualityprofiles/search.protobuf?projectKey=<key> | time=54ms
[INFO] 12:30:06.389 Load quality profiles (done) | time=65ms
[INFO] 12:30:06.407 Load active rules
[DEBUG] 12:30:06.686 GET 200 http://<ip>:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives&activation=true&qprofile=c%2B%2B-sonar-way-47212&p=1&ps=500 | time=278ms
....
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:33 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-04T12:30:06+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 244M/905M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project <project>: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project <project>: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:80)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:77)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.batch.rule.ActiveRules
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.readPage(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:99)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:59)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:102)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:63)
    at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
    ... 72 more
[ERROR]
```

**Any idea why I'm getting this failure:**

- I have customised my settings.xml to have the server settings and API key and the maven project is configured to be "java" in the root pom
- I can't seem to find the solution on any of the other threads.
- I have had the server setup to know about the project and verified that key does exists

FYI: I've substituted ,  and

Comment: can you check what is the object that is null in DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java line number 99

Comment: hope this link helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483971/sonar-maven-plugin3-1-1sonar-analyze-error-after-upgrade-to-sonarqube-6-0

Comment: Agh it maybe that, thanks :)
Although the sonar instance is not under my control, but I'll request that the workaround is applied and see if it works